# Run code when window closes

Tags: c#, winforms, settings

I believe it is possible to run code when the close button is pressed in Windows Forms application in C#. Its a child form of the main window. I want to save some user settings when the user closes the window.

```
private void fileTypeDialog_FormClosing(Object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        int ArraySize = fileTypesData.Items.Count;
        string[] fileTypesToSaveArray = new string[ArraySize];

        for (int i = 0; i < ArraySize; i++)
        {
            fileTypesToSaveArray[i] = fileTypesData.Items[i].ToString();
        }
        string fileTypesToSave = String.Join(",", fileTypesToSaveArray);
        MessageBox.Show(fileTypesToSave.ToString());
        Properties.Settings.Default.fileTypes = fileTypesToSave;
        Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
    }
```

I have done this before i think, but i simply cannot remember how i did it. Can you guys assist me?

Comment: What problems have you faced?

Comment: That code should work ANYTIME the form closes.  To control it better, test the e.CloseReason property.  You can also cancel the close if you want by setting e.Cancel = true;

Comment: Is the event wired up?  It's better to use the override: OnFormClosing instead to avoid a form having to listen to its own events.  Try avoid using a MessageBox for a debugging call, it can interfere with too many things.

Comment: LarsTech how do i wire it up? I guess it has something to do with the Form Designer somewhere. But i havent done anything besides the code you see. But for some reason it doesnt work for me. No messagebox is ever shown upon closing the window

Comment: @DanielJørgensen Use the @ sign in comments to notify them at Stack Overflow.  If you didn't use the designer to create that method, then in your constructor, you would have to type: `this.FormClosing += fileTypeDialog_FormClosing;`.  To avoid the event, just start typing "override OnForm" and select OnFormClosing from the intellisense.   Put your code in that code block.

Comment: @LarsTech - That did the trick! I had simply forgotten that part. Thanks for your assistance, you should probably add it as an answer for me to accept and others to see :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your event isn't wired up.  If you don't create the event with the designer, then you need to add it manually, usually in the constructor:

```
public Form1() {
  InitializeComponent();
  this.FormClosing += fileTypeDialog_FormClosing;
}
```

But a form shouldn't have to listen to its own events since it has access to its protected event methods.  So simply start typing "override OnForm" and select "OnFormClosing" from intellisense.  Your code block would look like this:

```
protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e) {
  // your code here

  base.OnFormClosing(e);
}
```

When overriding a base method, always include the base call as shown unless you have a specific reason not to.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use FormClosed instead of FormClosing, I tried and worked very well for me :) Hope helped you :)

Comment: Tried that. Does not change. Apparently this should work according to other comments, so something must be wrong on my end. Something that i have missed or forgotten